# Ruby array of hashes values to string

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, cucumber

I have an array of hashes (#1) that looks like this:

```
data = [{"username"=>"Luck", "mail"=>"root@localhost.net", "active"=>0}]
```

that I am trying to compare with following array of hashes (#2):

```
test = [{"username"=>"Luck", "mail"=>"root@localhost.net", "active"=>"0"}]
```

where #1 I obtained from database by mysql2 (what actually is in the database)
and #2 from my cucumber scenario (what I minimally expect ot be there).

By definition #2 must be a subset of #1 so I follow with this code:

```
data = data.to_set
test = test.to_set
assert test.subset?(data)
```

The problem is in data array the value of `active` is NOT a string. In case of `data` it is `Fixnum`, and in case of `test`, it is `String`.

I need a solution that will work even for more than one hash in the array. (As the database can return more than one row of results) That is why I convert to sets and use `subset?`

From other questions I got:

```
data.each do |obj|
  obj.map do |k, v|
    {k => v.to_s}
  end
end
```

However it does not work for me. Any ideas?

Assumptions you can make:

- All the keys in `data` will always be Strings.
- All the keys in `test` will always be Strings. And always be the identical to `data`.
- All the values in `test` will always be Strings.

Comment: what is the type if not a string? Can you update your example with the datatype it's showing.  Also is your goal to be able to say data == test?  Where does `subset` come from?

Comment: Corrected the question to provide the answers you are loking for. However for starters to get data == test would be good.

Comment: `test` is a sub-array of `data` if and only if `(test-data).empty? => true`. Is that what you want?  Note that if `h` and `g` are hashes, `h==g => true` if and only if they have the same keys and values, regardless of key order.

Comment: That is what i want, however, the data type of active in `test` is `String` and in `data` is `Fixnum`. That causes the whole problem.

Comment: I don't understand. You have `data = [h]` and `test = [g]`, where `h` and `g` are hashes that differ in the value of one key.  Are you saying that, for the purposes of `subset` you want `h` and `g` to be regarded as equal if they have the same keys and the same values after the values have been converted to strings?

Comment: Yes. What I am looking for is the code to convert the values to Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches that should do it, assuming I understand the question correctly.

**#1: convert the hash values to strings**

```
def stringify_hash_values(h)
  h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v.to_s }
end

def sorta_subset?(data,test)
  (test.map { |h| stringify_hash_values(data) } -
    data.map { |h| stringify_hash_values(data) }).empty?
end

data = [{"username"=>"Luck", "mail"=>"root@localhost.net", "active"=>0}]
test = [{"username"=>"Luck", "mail"=>"root@localhost.net", "active"=>"0"}]
sorta_subset?(data,test) #=> true
```

**#2 see if keys are the same and values converted to strings are equal**

```
require 'set'

def hashes_sorta_equal?(h,g)
  hk = h.keys
  (hk.to_set == g.keys.to_set) &&
    (h.values_at(*hk).map(&:to_s) == g.values_at(*hk).map(&:to_s))
end

def sorta_subset?(data,test)
  test.all? { |h| data.any? { |g| hashes_sorta_equal?(g,h) } }
end

sorta_subset?(data,test) #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why it works, but I found A solution:

```
data.map! do |obj|
  obj.each do |k, v|
    obj[k] = "#{v}"
  end
end
```

I think it has something to do with what functions on arrays and hashes change the object itself and not create a changed copy of the object.

Comment: It works because you are converting each element to strings. In your `data` array, `active` is mapped to a number, while it is mapped to a string in `test`. This was causing the comparison to fail.

Comment: That's what I was looking to do. I did it, however I am not exactly sure how this code segment did the work.

Comment: Yes, that converts the values to strings, which will allow you to use `data - test`, but watch out for unintended side-effects.  If, for example, you create a method `sorta_subset?(test,data)`, you need to recognize that `test` and `data` will have been changed in the calling method after `sorta_subset?` returns. In general, it is best not to change ("mutate") those arrays. Nor can you change the values in `dup`ed arrays.  See #1 in my solution for a way to do that without changing `data` or `test`.

Comment: @user1668376 : This will work, too: `data.each{|obj| obj.each{|k,v| obj[k] = v.to_s } }`

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right about the best practices. However this code is a quickfix to use Cucumber to test PHP application. It won't be reused and doesn't have to be perfect, so I don't mind slight 'hacks'. However for anyone else, I picked your solution as the right answer.